# Add directive dynamically when using angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

What would be the best way to add some directive, e.g. [ng-focus-if](https://github.com/hiebj/ng-focus-if) conditionally to the form's input element when using [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/) with custom templates?

I would like to use it like this:

```javascript
$scope.formFields = [
  {
    key: 'email',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Your E-Mail address',
      required: true,
      focusIf: 'some-expression' // <--- optional directive configuration here
    }
  }
];
```

The idea is to apply the directive only when configuration option is actually provided.

Comment: You'll want to look into [`ngModelAttrs`](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/very-advanced/ngModelAttrs). It's a bit complex, but by defining a custom type that has defines that as a defaultOption you can accomplish what you're looking for. Look at the [UI Mask](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-mask) example.

Comment: Hello Kent! Thank you for pushing me in the right direction! Just wanted to tell you that Formly is truly awesome and very flexible. I love Angular, but forms was a huge pain for me all the time, now it all sorted out, thanks to you. I've created a JSBin with my ngFocusIf integration, feel free to edit it according to your needs and add it to the list of examples. Cheers! https://jsbin.com/vimayu/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combining  **angular-formly** attributes with **ng-focus-if** attributes or any others custom attributes by using  **ngModelAttrs**.

in your case your code should be like:

```
 $scope.formFields = [ {
        key: 'email',
        type: 'input',
         ngModelAttrs: {
              focusIf: {
                attribute: 'focus-if'   //directive declaration
              }
            },
        templateOptions: {
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'Your E-Mail address',
          focusIf: '', //directive default value
          required: true           
        }       
      }]
```

this is a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/lrM3P8m8pZOEqdFGodJt) that can help you:

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to figure out how to achieve the desired behavior, thanks to @kentcdodds and @aitnasser.

Just wanted to share the extended version here.

The idea is to use [**ngModelAttrs**](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/ngmodelattrs) property when defining your type:

```javascript
formlyConfigProvider.setType({
  name: 'input',
  template: '<input ng-model="model[options.key]">',
  defaultOptions: {
    ngModelAttrs: {
      focusIf: {
        attribute: 'focus-if'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Make sure not to provide the default value for the `focusIf`. This will prevent addition of the directive on the input element by default.

And then set the required expression on your field:

```javascript
$scope.formFields = [
 {
   key: 'email',
   type: 'input',
   templateOptions: {
     type: 'email',
     required: true,
     placeholder: 'E-Mail',
     focusIf: 'true' // Or any other Angular expression
   }
 }
];
```

Feel free to play with this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vimayu/3/edit?html,js,output).